# Where does Magento calculate the "Average Orders" value from the dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

Looking at the dashboard, I see the "Average Orders" value on the left side. I want to exclude orders from that calculation. Where do I have to look to make that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average is calculated here:

```
\Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection::calculateSales
$averageExpr = $adapter->getCheckSql(
                'SUM(main_table.orders_count) > 0',
                'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)/SUM(main_table.orders_count)',
                0);
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'lifetime' => 'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)',
                'average'  => $averageExpr
            ));
```

Comment: That looks promising!